# C language : source file after preprocessing

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Am using visual **cl.exe** compiler to get an intermediate file after preprocessing. 
all the `#define` are removed. is there any possibility to keep them in the intermediate file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. One of the tasks of the preprocessing is to remove all #define and others preprocessing stuffs the #s and creates a plain c file.

What you can do:
use the /E or /P to output the preprocess to the output or file: http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/clexe-cmd-line-args.html

Answer (score 1):

`#define` is a preprocessor instruction so obviously it won't be present in a preprocessed source file. Every occurrence of a preprocessor constant will be replaced with its actual value by the preprocessor.